# Too many objects on one screen. Suggestions

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a activity screen that pulls mysql data for 1 record only (never more then 1). I need to display all this information on the screen. I placed the feild the way I want but I am getting a notification that I have too many objects on the screen. I have read several different answers about using a listview, but I dont think that applies here because I am only displaying 1 record. I currently have all the data placed in a table format. Can I get some input on what changes I can make to the layout to make it more streamlined.

```
activity_loads.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoadsActivity"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/LoadNumber"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="@string/AddlStops"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewLoadNumber"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAddlStops"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ShipperName"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipName"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ShipperAddr" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipAddr"
            android:textColor="#0404b4"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/MapIt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ShipMap"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipAddr2"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipCity"
            android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipState"
            android:textColor="#0404b4"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ShipperPhone"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipPhone"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ShipperContact"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewShipContact"
            android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/PUDateTime"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPUDate"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPUTime"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/CustomerPO"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCustomerPO"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Weight"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewWeight"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Pieces"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPieces"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/BLNumber"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewBLNumber"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/TrlrNumber"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTrlrNumber"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#229954"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ConsigneeName"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsName"
            android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ConsigneeAddr"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsAddr"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/MapIt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ConsMap"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsAddr2"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsCity"
            android:layout_marginStart="142dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsState"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ConsigneePhone"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsPhone"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/ConsigneeContact"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewConsContact"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:textColor="#0404b4" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/DelDateTime"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDelDate"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDelTime"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/DrvLoad"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDrvLoad"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/DrvUnload"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDrvUnload"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/LoadedMiles"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewLoaded"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/EmptyMiles"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewEmpty"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/TempLow"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTempLow"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/TempHigh"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTempHigh"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Preloaded"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPreload"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/DropHook"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDropHook"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/Comments"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewComments"
            />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: This is the desired result]

Comment: you have to re-think your design ... find a designer maybe !? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, regardless of the issue, this design is counter-intuitive and hard to read. Instead of framing it as a table, use a listview where you would add each row to the list or if the fields are static then create a static scrollview and populate the texts with the data queried from your db.

Comment: I will attempt to rewrite the page, however, I am limited due to the fact this information is pulled from a mainframe. I am learning about the flexability of listviews and custom adapters. I am not sure about a static scollview, but I will check into it.